# Exception returning no exception

Tags: python

I got a code something like this:

```
try:
     do_something()
except (urllib2.URLError, socket.timeout), er:
     print something 
except Exception, ex:
     print "The code failed because", ex, "Please review"
```

Now, the problem is on executing the above code I am getting following output:

```
The code failed because Please review
```

p.s.: The 'ex' should return the name of the exception but its not returning anything. Any idea why?

In reference to @Yuji and @Peter, I tried this code:

```
try:
    try:
           print x
    except Exception, ex:
           print "ex:", ex
           raise
except Exception, er:
    print "er:", er
```

And the Output was:

```
ex: name 'x' is not defined .
er: name 'x' is not defined .
```

Now, why raise(er) is returning an error? And why it does not in you cases?

Comment: Maybe something just did a `raise Exception`?

Comment: @Yuji: can you please elaborate? May be with an example where raise at somewhere causes exception returning nothing.

Comment: @dragonsrsupercool for example, printing the exception message for `raise Exception` prints nothing. printing the exception for `raise Exception('foo')` or `raise Exception, 'foo'` prints "foo"

Comment: @Yuji: I have added a code block above, can you please review and tell why raise is returning error in my case but not in yours?

Comment: @dragonsrsupercool - you are not raising an exception, python is raising an exception because `x` is not defined, and the exception message for that `NameError` is "name 'x' is not defined". Update: the `raise` in the outer block is re-raising the first exception as it's supposed to

Comment: @Yuji: Can we get trace-back or exception which caused the raise? If yes then how?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5257/discussion-between-dragosrsupercool-and-yuji-tomita)

Comment: You could look into the `traceback` module to generate a ... traceback for the exception: http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily - the expectation is not entirely true. The following code prints nothing:

```
try:
    raise BaseException()
except BaseException, ex:
    print ex
```

But this prints "abc":

```
try:
    raise BaseException("abc")
except BaseException, ex:
    print ex
```